# I accidentally removed python2.7 executable

Tags: python, exe

I accidentally removed /usr/bin/python2.7 executable file with
rm /usr/bin/python2.7
how can I restore it?
Thank you

Comment: You can't restore it per se,  you should just reinstall python if you don't want to mess with some restoration utilities. There's no trash can for a `rm` command, the data is unlinked.

Comment: Pretty much every distro has a way to repair or reinstall damaged packages (i.e. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7` for `apt-get`-based distros etc.). Find how to repair a package for your distro.

Comment: @exabytes.js - What is the OP supposed to click on when they're seemingly using a headless linux box?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7 gives me : Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1). How can this be fixed? @zwer

Comment: I've run these lines, but it's still not working
# refreshing the repositories
sudo apt update
# its wise to keep the system up to date!
# you can skip the following line if you not
# want to update all your software
sudo apt upgrade
# installing python 2.7 and pip for it
sudo apt install python2.7 python-pip

Comment: @SuminKim What's the full `dpkg` error message? You may be able to fix things by running `apt install -f`.

Comment: @Florian Weimer I've tried
$sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
and the error message was Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @SuminKim There will be additional error message before that. We cannot help you until you show them to us.

Comment: Ok, please stay with me.. It's too long to post in one comment and I'll split it up! @Florian Weimer

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of python2.7 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

Comment: cdbs dh-translations intltool libappindicator1 libindicator7 libjpeg-dev
  libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev liblzma-dev python-scour python-six
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Comment: Setting up python2.7 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.postinst: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.postinst: /usr/bin/python2.7: not found
dpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I had to reinstall ubuntu in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get past the postinst error, you can put `true` as a dummy executable in the place of `/usr/bin/python2.7`:

```
cp /bin/true /usr/bin/python2.7
```

Then you should be able to fix the installation using:

```
apt install -f
```

After this point, you should be able to reinstall `python2.7` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
```

This should bring back the `python2.7` executable for real.

Note that this question is more suited to the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) site.

Comment: hi, after fixing this problem, I tried to make a simbolic link by $sudo ln -f -v /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2
'/usr/bin/python2' => '/usr/bin/python2.7'
but when I check the version by
$ python2 --versiontrue (GNU coreutils) 8.25
I get something like

Comment: true (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: And when I type $python2, it doesn't give me a python prompt. There is not even a error message.
Is this due to the dummy variable I'd used? Is there a way to fix this? Thank you. @Florian Weimer

Comment: I think you may also have to reinstall the `python2` package.

Comment: I've searched online for some solutions, and I found this. I'm afraid of using rm command so could you tell me if this is a safe way?
1.Remove the current dead link.

rm /usr/bin/python

2.Recreate the link

ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
@Florian Weimer

Comment: Reinstalling `python2` and `python2.7` again should hopefully fix this, and should be quite risk-free.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But could you explain how to install python2? I've tried
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python2
How can I reinstall python2 package? Sorry I'm a newbie at python.. @Florian Weimer

Comment: Maybe it's called `python` on your distribution?

Comment: I've tried $ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python, but it gave me the same error message. And I'm also struggling to install pip. $pip install numpy also does not give me any messages. The command doesn't seem to be executed and just throws me another prompt without doing anything @Florian Weimer

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: It's 16.04. I've uploaded my problem here. Thank you. https://superuser.com/questions/1363592/unable-to-symlink-usr-bin-python2-7-to-usr-bin-python-or-to-usr-bin-python2
@Florian Weimer

Comment: I'm now having this issue too @SuminKim and I can tell the Florian Weimer advice misled us and broke our ubuntu. shame on you, Florian. I now have to reinstall my ubuntu server